# .NET export to excel - not showing list property

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, datatable, export-to-excel, closedxml

I am trying to export a .xlsx document from the controller when the user clicks a button. My model looks like this:

```
public class ExportOrdersViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public string CustomerMobile { get; set; }
    public string ShippingStreet { get; set; }
    public string ShippingCity { get; set; }
    public string ShippingCountry { get; set; }
    public string ShippingPostalCode { get; set; }
    public string ShippingTo { get; set; }
    public bool IsShipped { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ExportOrdersItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

}

public class ExportOrdersItemViewModel
{
    public string TicketName { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public string PaymentCurrencyId { get; set; }
    public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string PaymentUnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Besides string properties, ExportOrdersViewModel contains a list of items. When the file is created, I want to display this list in a cell when the row is created.

I am using ClosedXML in order to create the file. Before the file is created, in the controller I created a DataTable that contains all the ExportOrdersViewModel properties and one row that references another DataTable which contains the properties for ExportOrdersItemViewModel. The parrent DataTable is passed to the workbook aftee this.

Here you can see How I am doing it:

```
        DataTable orders = new DataTable();

        orders.Columns.Add("OrderID", typeof(string));
        orders.Columns.Add("Items", typeof(DataTable));
        orders.Columns.Add("IsShipped", typeof(bool));

        DataTable items = new DataTable();
        items.Columns.Add("TicketName", typeof(string));
        items.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
        items.Columns.Add("Currency", typeof(string));


        exportModels.ForEach(o => orders.Rows.Add(
                                            o.Id,
                                           (DataTable)GetItems(o.Items),
                                            o.IsShipped
                                            ));
```

when I check in the debug mode the orders DataTable, it contains references to the corresponding items DataTable, but when I pass is to the workbook, the file items row is empty.

Here is how I am creating the file:

```
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        workbook.Worksheets.Add(orders, "Orders");

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"HelloWorld.xlsx\"");

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            memoryStream.Close();
        }

        Response.End();
```

This is a printscreen with the output File:[image]

And i want to make it look like this: https://aspblogs.blob.core.windows.net/media/muhanadyounis/Media/linqParentChild_615EF617.jpg

Comment: is https://aspblogs.blob.core.windows.net/media/muhanadyounis/Media/linqParentChild_615EF617.jpg a screenshot of Excel? Doesn't look like it is.

Comment: It isn't. I just wanted to make it look like that

Comment: Not possible in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found a suitable solution for this. I am appending to the worksheet a new table every time. Here is how I did it:

```
   //HELPER METHODS
    private DataTable GetItems(ICollection<ExportOrdersItemViewModel> list)
    {
        var items = new DataTable();

        items.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.OrderTicketName, typeof(string));
        items.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.OrderEventName, typeof(string));
        items.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.Quantity, typeof(int));
        items.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.Currency, typeof(string));
        items.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.PaymentCurrencyId, typeof(string));
        items.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.UnitPrice, typeof(string));
        items.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.PaymentUnitPrice, typeof(string));
        list.ForEach(i => items.Rows.Add(i.TicketName, i.EventName, i.Quantity, i.CurrencyId, i.PaymentCurrencyId, i.UnitPrice, i.PaymentUnitPrice));

        return items;
    }

    private void SetOrdersProperties(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.OrderId, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.OrderDate, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.InvoicedDate, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.CustomerFirstname, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.CustomerLastName, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.CustomerEmail, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.CustomerPhone, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.ShipTo, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.ShippingStreet, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.City, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.ShippingPostalCode, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.ShippingCountry, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.IsShipped, typeof(string));
    }

    private void SetItemsProperties(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.OrderTicketName, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.OrderEventName, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.Quantity, typeof(int));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.Currency, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.PaymentCurrencyId, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.UnitPrice, typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Names.PaymentUnitPrice, typeof(string));
    }
```

I used those methods to create a DataTable with items and set the tableHeaders for orders and items.
In the next piece of code is the way i created my file:

```
 DataTable orders = new DataTable();
        SetOrdersProperties(orders);

        DataTable items = new DataTable();
        SetItemsProperties(items);

        XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        var workSheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Orders");


        var index = 1;
        exportModels.ForEach(o =>
                            {
                                orders.Rows.Add(
                                             o.Id,
                                             o.OrderDate,
                                             o.InvoicedDate,
                                             o.CustomerFirstName,
                                             o.CustomerLastName,
                                             o.CustomerEmail,
                                             o.CustomerMobile,
                                             o.ShippingTo,
                                             o.ShippingStreet,
                                             o.ShippingCity,
                                             o.ShippingPostalCode,
                                             o.ShippingCountry,
                                             o.IsShipped ? "YES":"NO"
                                             );
                                workSheet.Cell(index, 1).InsertTable(orders);
                                index += orders.Rows.Count+1;
                                orders = new DataTable();
                                SetOrdersProperties(orders);
                                workSheet.Cell(index, 2).InsertTable(GetItems(o.Items));
                                workSheet.Cell(index, 1).Value = Resources.Names.Tickets;
                                workSheet.Range(index, 1, index + o.Items.Count,1).Merge();
                                index += o.Items.Count()+1;
                                index++;
                            });

        workSheet.Tables.ForEach(t => t.ShowAutoFilter = false);
        workSheet.Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
        workSheet.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        workSheet.Tables.ForEach(t => t.Theme = XLTableTheme.TableStyleLight13);
```